# Nested p:dataTable loading involuntarily on rowToggle event for collapsed records

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

**Page Structure:**
My page has a main table called **carsDtble**, listing out the available cars in the Store. This table has a nested table inside p:rowExpansion called **colorsDtble** listing out all the available colors for the selected car.

**Problem** -- When i click on the row Expansion for a car say Ford, the ideal behavior is to load the colors table only for Ford Car. But i see that all the nested Colors Tables are being loaded.

This behaviour in my original business usecase is creating a heavy overhead while loading the page as there might be 100's of records present in the Cars Table.

**a.** **carsController** (ViewAccessScoped) - provides the data for the main table

```
@ViewAccessScoped
@Named("carsController")
public class CarsController implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<String> cars;

    public List<String> getCars(){
       cars=new ArrayList<>();
        cars.add("Lamborghini  - Huracan");
        cars.add("Ford  -Mustang");
        cars.add("Ferrari  - 488 GTB");
        cars.add("Land Rover  -Range Rover");

        return cars;
    }
}
```

**b.** **colorsController** (Session Scoped) - provides the data for nested Table

```
@SessionScoped
@Named("colorsController")
public class ColorsController implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    List<String> colors;

    private String expandedCarId;

    public List<String> getCarColors(String carId){

      System.out.println("Generating the sub table records for loan      `:"+carId);`
      colors=new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add(carId +"-Yellow");
        colors.add(carId +"-Red");
        colors.add(carId +"-White");
        colors.add(carId +"-Green");
        colors.add(carId +"-Black");

        return colors;
    }

}
```

**c.** nestedTable.xhtml

```html
<f:view contentType="text/html" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
  <h:form id="carDetailForm">
   <h:body class="bgcolor">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="main-context" id="scrollArea">

      <p:accordionPanel id="carListAcrdPnl" width="100%"
       styleClass="accordionPanel accordionPanelScroll">
       <p:tab id="carTab" title="Allocated Cars">

        <p:dataTable id="carsDtble" var="car"
         value="#{carsController.getCars()}" styleClass="table-scroll"
         paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
         paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
         rows="20" rowsPerPageTemplate="20,40,60"
         style="max-height: 550px !important;" sortMode="multiple"
         rowIndexVar="index">
         <p:columnGroup type="header">
          <p:row>
           <p:column></p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Car " sortBy="#{car}"></p:column>
          </p:row>
         </p:columnGroup>
         <p:column style="width:2%">
          <p:rowToggler />
         </p:column>
         <p:column styleClass="ralign">#{car}</p:column>

         <p:ajax event="rowToggle"
          onstart="return cfg.ext.params[0].name.indexOf('_rowExpansion') != -1"
           />
         <p:rowExpansion id="rowExpansionSection"
          styleClass="ui-datatable-empty-message">
          <p:panel style="width:90% !important;margin-left:50px">
           <p:dataTable id="colorsDtble"
            value="#{colorsController.getCarColors(car)}" var="color"
            styleClass="table-scroll"
            emptyMessage="Car Color Information is not Found.">
            <p:columnGroup type="header">
             <p:row>
              <p:column headerText="Color"></p:column>
             </p:row>
            </p:columnGroup>

            <p:column styleClass="ralign">
             <h:outputText id="clrTxt" value="#{color}">
             </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
           </p:dataTable>
          </p:panel>
         </p:rowExpansion>

        </p:dataTable>
       </p:tab>
      </p:accordionPanel>

     </div>
    </div>
   </h:body>
  </h:form>
 </f:view>
```

Comment: Why do you use `<h:body>` inside `<h:form>`?

Comment: I only see one action in your code and you update the full form in there, so including the datatable (or do I miss something)

Comment: hi @Kukeltje. on clicking the button i'm loading the values for Outer Table and i'm updating the Form to reflect the data on the screen. When the users expands the toggler i expect primefaces would then instantiate the inner table.

Comment: Rowexpansion is not lazy. It is updated at the same time the outer datatable is updated. So it is never unvoluntarily updating on every ajax call.

Comment: The content embedded inside <p:rowExpansion> should not be loaded for all the others records other than the expanded record right.?  when we expand the first record only the contents of the first row should be instantiated. I'm observing the controller call for inner Table is being called for all the others rows present in the table irrespective if they expanded or not